# 'MultiBinding' cannot be used within a 'SetterBaseCollection'

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I just started to programm in C# and got the following error message "A 'MultiBinding' cannot be used within a 'SetterBaseCollection' collection. A 'MultiBinding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject". My dea was to disable some of the combobox depedant of the input values given to the converter.  use the same converter later in the xaml file and have no error..

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxDirectionCellDataTemplate">
         <Canvas>
            <ComboBox Name="DirectionBi" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DirectionBiList}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Direction, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="#FFCDCDCD" />
            <ComboBox Name="DirectionOut" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DirectionOutList}}" SelectedItem="{Binding PinFunctionOptions[SelectedPinFunctionIdx].SupportedDirections, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="#FFCDCDCD" />
            <ComboBox Name="DirectionIn" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DirectionOutList}}" SelectedItem="{Binding PinFunctionOptions[SelectedPinFunctionIdx].SupportedDirections, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="#FFCDCDCD" />
        </Canvas>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="In">
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FunctionToGroupConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="PinFunctionOptions"/>
                    <Binding Path="SelectedPinFunctionIdx"/>
                </MultiBinding>
                <Setter TargetName="DirectionBi" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
```

Thanks for help!!!!

Answer (score 4):

I may be wrong - and i have no way of checking this at the moment...

I think what you want is the following...

```
<DataTrigger ...>
<DataTrigger.Binding>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FunctionToGroupConverter}">
        <Binding Path="PinFunctionOptions"/>
        <Binding Path="SelectedPinFunctionIdx"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</DataTrigger.Binding>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Hi, the error doesn't appear anymore with this change, but both values are empty in the converter. But I got no error message in the output window that the binding fails?

Comment: This solves the this question then - binding simply works here if it does compile (you have to catch in your converter and see what other problems are). I could have no idea what `PinFunctionOptions` etc. does. I'd suggest to close this one - and open another question with more details for the next problem. It's how SO works - and you'd get best attention that way (nobody else will look into this usually)

Answer (score -2):

`DataTemplate.Triggers` is expecting a collection of `Setter` why are you attempting to put a `MultiBinding` in there?

The exception you're getting is a result of this.

I'm not entirely certain what you're attempting with the `MultiBinding` but you may fare better by performing the bindings individually on the respective elements.

Comment: Hi thanx,I only want to use MultiBinding for the converter and not for the Setter. Maybe the notation is wrong? My first approach was to perform the bindings on the elements, but my modell consist of a collection and he index of the element but I found no way to get he selected entry. (something like this PinFunctionOptions[SelectedPinFunctionIdx].SupportedDirections)

Comment: Hmmmm, without the actual code to go on I'm afraid I can't offer much help, but yes, your problem is having the `MultiBinding` where it is, it won't like it being there.